# What is purpose of init_app function in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Example: db.init_app(app)

What is purpose of init_app function in Flask? Is this like any other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A number of packages provide an `init_app()` method. It's a way of constructing an instance of the particular package, then letting it know about the `Flask` instance (e.g., so that configuration details can be copied). Mechanically, it's just like any other instance method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to safely bind database handler to Flask app in a way that manages connections.

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.init_app

Answer (score 0):

It is used to control the integration of a package to one or more Flask applications. Depending on how you initialize the object it is usable right away or will attach as needed to a Flask application. 
In the case of db.init_app(app) the app is your flask application,the object must have been created initially.